# KDB top rows for each group

Tags: kdb

I want to query top 5 salary earners form dept table SQL Like

```
    SELECT * FROM (
                    SELECT empno, salary, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY salary DESC) emprank FROM emp ) 
    WHERE emprank <= 3;
```

I was trying to do somthing like..

```
select from emp where ({x in 3#x};i) fby deptno
```

but not able to produce expected result. Please can you give me a clue.

Comment: How did you want to handle the edge condition if there are ties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be:

```
select 3 sublist salary idesc[salary] by deptno from emp
```

`sublist` was used rather than `#` to handle the case were a department has less than 3 salaries.

Answer (score 4):

Where t is:

```
t:([]deptno:where 10 20 8;salary:40000+38?30000;emp:neg[38]?`3)
```

You can return the top 3 highest earners by department with the following

```
q)select from t where 3>(iasc idesc@;salary)fby deptno
deptno salary emp
-----------------
0      69894  mfm
0      55539  bbb
0      62673  jnd
1      66668  afk
1      67474  kcj
1      69979  kon
2      60561  oco
2      57664  khd
2      58743  dga
```

Please note I used table t purely as an example table. Let me know if the table you have used differs significantly from the one I have here.

Answer (score 1):

Other alternative which executes faster and takes less memory:

```
q) select from t where ({til[count x] in 3#idesc x};salary) fby deptno
```

In case you want all the employees that comes under top 3 salary bucket, you could use below solution.

```
q) select from t where ({x in x 3#idesc x};salary) fby deptno
```

If your table is not ordered by deptno then could use 'xasc/xdesc' to order your result:

```
q) `deptno xasc select from t where ({til[count x] in 3#idesc x};salary) fby deptno
```